# STM32 .hex file convert to .dup file

Tags: hex, stm32, dup

I used STM32 IDE to create a .hex extension.

But need convert this .hex file to .dup file(for FOTA).

Previous convert tool was lost. I just have the flow like this.

```
stm32.py full fileName.hex > fileName.hupg
upgrade-gen.py hupg fileName.hupg -o fileName.dup
```

Does anybody know who to do or have regarding these tool?

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what exactly is not working.

Comment: How can we know what your python files are doing ?

Comment: As a side note, if I remember correctly .dup is a windows format, it's weird you're using it on an embedded system